# Spring security using JPA. How to configure applicationContext-security.XML file?(using DaoAuthenticationProvider)

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-mvc, spring-security

I was using JDBC Authentication service for my security.
code of authentication provider is ,

```
<authentication-provider>
    <jdbc-user-service id="userDetailsService" data-source-ref="dataSource" />
</authentication-provider>
```

And for data source,

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" >
  <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" /> 
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demodata" /> 
  <property name="username" value="root"/> 
  <property name="password" value="root"/> 
</bean>
```

Also I was using **daoAuthenticationProvider** , code of that is,

```
<beans:bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.providers.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
  <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService"/>
  <property name="saltSource" ref bean="saltSource"/>
  <property name="passwordEncoder" ref="passwordEncoder"/>
</beans:bean>
```

And It was working properly.
Now I want to use **JPA** connection instead of **JDBC**.
So I Created new class **CustomUserDetailsService** which **implements UserDetailsService** Interface. Now My authentication provider looks like,

```
<authentication-provider  user-service-ref="CustomUserDetailsService">
</authentication-provider>
<beans:bean id="CustomUserDetailsService" class="com.service.CustomUserDetailsService" />
```

Authentication manager's code :

```
<beans:bean id="authenticationManager"
        class="org.springframework.security.providers.ProviderManager">
        <beans:property name="providers"><beans:list>
                <beans:ref local="daoAuthenticationProvider" />
        </beans:list> </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="sessionController"
            ref="defaultConcurrentSessionController" />
</beans:bean>
```

Problem is that, Now how do I give its reference in **daoAuthenticationProvider's property userDetailsService**?
Thank you in advance. (I can provide more information if needed)

Comment: Why do you need two separate authentication providers (one defined by `<authentication-provider>` and another defined as a bean)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

??? Just reference the new UserDetailsService by id:

```
<beans:bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider"
  class="org.springframework.security.providers.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
  <property name="userDetailsService" ref="CustomUserDetailsService"/>
  <property name="saltSource" ref bean="saltSource"/>
  <property name="passwordEncoder" ref="passwordEncoder"/>
</beans:bean>
```

Or am I missing something?

Comment: I tried that, But its not working. It says authentication provider not found.

Comment: @sagar the id probably needs to be authenticationProvider, not daoAuthenticationProvider. Spring uses naming conventions like that in many places

Comment: P. F. :I added Code of my authentication manager.As it has property provider so I think we can give any name to ID and just refer it in authentication manager.

Comment: I tried your solution but still It says  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No authentication providers were found in the application context

Comment: your answer was more appropriate. Actually problem was in my "CustomUserDetailsService". I forgot to set property of that bean thinking that spring annotation @autowire will do that. But I guess annotation doesn't work with spring security.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
<authentication-provider  user-service-ref="CustomUserDetailsService">
</authentication-provider>
<beans:bean id="CustomUserDetailsService" 
    class="com.service.CustomUserDetailsService" />
```

Can you try the following as suggested [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/2.0.x/reference/appendix-namespace.html#d4e3397)?

```
<beans:bean id="CustomUserDetailsService" class="com.service.CustomUserDetailsService">
    <custom-authentication-provider/>
</beans>
```

Comment: OMG! it worked. Thankyou very much. But I am in another mess now.see if you can help. java.lang.NullPointerException com.service.CustomUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(CustomUserDetailsService.java:27). I think there is an error in my overrrided method.

Comment: @Sagar. It would be better if you ask a new question for this with the code snippet and the full stacktrace so that someone can help.

Comment: It seemed to be correct answer but it wasn't. we created custom user details service not custom-authentication-provider.